# Finding lower bounds for solution of linear Diophantine equation in two variables

Tags: inequality, algorithms, arithmetic

I am currently encountering the following arithmetical problem:
given four nonzero integers $A,B,C,D$, let 
$\Omega=\bigg\lbrace (x,y)\in{\mathbb N_{\geq 0}}^2 \ \bigg| \ 
\frac{Ax+By}{Cx+Dy} \in {\mathbb Z} \ \bigg\rbrace$
and suppose that $\Omega$ is non-empty.

Let then $\mu$ be the minimum value of all ${\sf min}(x,y)$ where
$(x,y)\in \Omega$.

Is it easy to compute $\mu$ from $A,B,C,D$? If not, can one find
a “reasonably good” lower bound for $\mu$?

A concrete example:

If

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
A &=& 522834163445445988434458010516405 \\
B &=& -3063742572717320569341511991159738 \\
C &=& 1666455861030599542832067804101203 \\
D &=& - 9765222175513935643148512770417523 \\
\end{array}
$$

can $\mu$ be computed exactly or up to a reasonable precision?